# Questions about egit and github/travis

Tags: eclipse, github, travis-ci, egit, sonarcloud

i'm a beginner java developer, i need to use eclipse and i have some questions about eclipse/github/egit/jgit/travis.

1. I need to get the commits made on a repository in github. I found on the internet that this is possible with both jgit and egit and more in depth that egit uses jgit. My first question is: are jgit and egit functionally equivalent? (all i can do with egit i can do it with jgit and vice versa)?
2. To get the date of a commit with egit I have to write something like `commit.getAuthor().getDate()`, why does this work? That is, `commit.getAuthor()` returns an instance of the `class CommitUser`, why a method of the `class CommitUser` returns the commit date? shouldn't `getDate()` be a method of the `class Commit`?
3. My project must be loaded into a repository managed through SVN and on which I will have to use the tools travis and sonarcloud. My question is: how does the management of external jars added to the project take place when I use travis and sonarcloud? Will I get errors? How should I handle them?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr first: your comment doesn't help. second: I have to analyze a project that has 2617 commits, doing this manually is madness. third: I don't think I'm the first or the last to do this since there are tools to support it, so I don't see what's so strange that needs to be underlined by a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) is a Java implementation of Git and used by [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) (= Eclipse IDE Git support) and other Java applications and frameworks, e.g. by [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/).
2. That's JGit, not EGit. A commit has two dates, the **authored date** (when it was committed) and the **committed date** (when it was pushed).
3. In a plain Java application [JGit can be used as Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit), the Eclipse IDE is not required to build your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Just to be safe about the point 2: the code I wrote above are taken from my project whose imports are: 
    `import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.Repository;
    import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.RepositoryCommit;
    import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.GitHubClient;
    import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.CommitService;
    import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.RepositoryService;`.

As you can see, i don't have imports like `org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git`.

Comment: [`org.eclipse.egit.github.core`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit-github.git/tree/) is the GitHub Mylyn integration for EGit (for GitHub specific stuff like issue tracker, etc.). To get the commits made on a Git repository you should use JGit only. At least that's how I did it.